# Doubling the reason for the flood in the Torah

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit

At the end of [Parashat Bereishit (6,7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.6.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) the Torah repeats two very similar statements twice - in a form of "ABAB" instead of "AABB":

> Aוַיִּרְא֤וּ בְנֵי־הָֽאֱלֹהִים֙ ...וַיִּקְח֤וּ לָהֶם֙ נָשִׁ֔ים מִכֹּ֖ל אֲשֶׁ֥ר בָּחָֽרוּ׃
>   the divine beings ...took wives from among those that pleased them.
>
> Bוַיֹּ֣אמֶר ה' לֹֽא־יָד֨וֹן רוּחִ֤י בָֽאָדָם֙ ...׃
>   The LORD said, “My breath shall not abide in man forever, ...”
>
> Aהַנְּפִלִ֞ים הָי֣וּ בָאָרֶץ֮ .. אֲשֶׁ֨ר יָבֹ֜אוּ בְּנֵ֤י הָֽאֱלֹהִים֙ אֶל־בְּנ֣וֹת הָֽאָדָ֔ם וְיָלְד֖וּ לָהֶ֑ם ...׃
>   ...the Nephilim appeared on earth—when the divine beings cohabited with the daughters of men, who bore them offspring...
>
> Bוַיַּ֣רְא ה' כִּ֥י רַבָּ֛ה רָעַ֥ת הָאָדָ֖ם ...׃
>   The LORD saw how great was man’s wickedness on earth...
>   וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֶמְחֶ֨ה אֶת־הָאָדָ֤ם אֲשֶׁר־בָּרָ֙אתִי֙ מֵעַל֙ פְּנֵ֣י הָֽאֲדָמָ֔ה ...׃
>   The LORD said, “I will blot out from the earth the men whom I created—men together with beasts, creeping things, and birds of the sky; for I regret that I made them.”

Why is this repeating order?